# Software for animation and sprite sheet generation

Tags: animation, sprite

Is there a software for making a sprite animation and produsing a sprite sheet?
Working fith photoshop's layers is very annoying for each frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure there is, Sprite Animation Sowtware allows you to create animation using static textures and save it as a sprite sheet or .gif animation.  See the details in http://spritetools.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.